# How to find tags that are not surrounded by specific tags and wrap them with tags

Tags: python, html, beautifulsoup

Using Beautifulsoup, I want to find `<a>` not enclosed by `<p>` and enclose it with `<p>` but I do not know how to do it

```
<p><a href="example1.com">example1.com</a></p>
<p><a href="example2.com">example2.com</a></p>
<a href="example3.com">example3.com</a>
<p><a href="example3.com">example3.com</a></p>
```

I would like to change html as above

```
<p><a href="example1.com">example1.com</a></p>
<p><a href="example2.com">example2.com</a></p>
<p><a href="example3.com">example3.com</a></p> <-here
<p><a href="example3.com">example3.com</a></p>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to select those anchors using [css selector](https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#css-selectors) and [`wrap`](https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#wrap) each of them with `p` tag

```
In [2]: from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as BS

In [3]: html = """<p><a href="example1.com">example1.com</a></p>
   ...: <p><a href="example2.com">example2.com</a></p>
   ...: <a href="example3.com">example3.com</a>
   ...: <p><a href="example3.com">example3.com</a></p>"""

In [4]: soup = BS(html, "html.parser")

In [5]: for a in soup.select("p ~ a"):
   ...:     a.wrap(soup.new_tag("p"))
   ...:     

In [6]: soup
Out[6]: 
<p><a href="example1.com">example1.com</a></p>
<p><a href="example2.com">example2.com</a></p>
<p><a href="example3.com">example3.com</a></p>
<p><a href="example3.com">example3.com</a></p>
```

Answer (score 1):

```
soup = BeautifulSoup(...)
items = soup.find_all('a')
for item in items:
    if item.parent.name != u'p':
        item.wrap(soup.new_tag('p'))
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

    data = """
    <p><a href="example1.com">example1.com</a></p>
    <p><a href="example2.com">example2.com</a></p>
    <a href="example3.com">example3.com</a>
    <p><a href="example3.com">example3.com</a></p>
    """


    soup = BeautifulSoup(data, 'html.parser')
    for a in soup('a'):  # shortcut for soup.find_all('p')

        if a.parent.name != 'p' :
            a.wrap(soup.new_tag("p"))
    print soup
```